# Are there historical cults/sects who venerated Judas?

Tags: religious-history

In the (HBO) Max series, 30 Coins (30 Monedas in Spanish), the antagonists are part of the Cult of Judas. This cult believed that because Jesus was sent to Earth to die for our sins, Judas's betrayal of him was the most important human act in history. Additionally, they believed that anyone who does an evil act like Judas is making good works possible by providing a contrast and and proving free will (roughly summarized).

My question for the historians is are there any equivalent movements in history that either believed:

1. Judas's betrayal was a deeply important act to Christianity, or
2. One should do evil acts to further God's will (and not the regular evil that historical persons have done in the name of God)?

Comment: If an act is furthering God's will, doesn't that make it good? In Christian belief God's will pretty much defines 'good'.

Comment: This might be Catholic theology -- Tolkien specifically wrote something like this.

Comment: Look up the [Gospel of Judas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Judas) and the [Cainites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cainites).

Comment: Judas the son of Jacob is very much venerated by Jews, from which the terms Jew and Jewish come from, as well as names like Yehuda and Jude. Early Christians possibly adopted gis name for the traitor to paint themselves as opponents to Jews, who were actively persecuted by Romans after successive revolts, and if which Christians were initially a sect.

Comment: @RogerVadim Judas is the greek translation of the hebrew name Yehuda יְהוּדָה, not the other way around.

Comment: @ccprog yes, obviously - does my comment puts this in diubt??

Comment: @RogerVadim Actually yes: "Judas..., from which the terms...come from, as well as names like Yehuda..."

Comment: @ccprog well, they all come from the original Hebrew term - I thought it should have been obvious from the context.

Comment: Minor thing: in Spanish it's "monedas", not "moniedas".

Comment: You may be interested in the related concept of [_Felix Culpa_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_culpa) or "Fortunate Fall"

Comment: these ideas are not catholic. god's will = good, yes, but also = reason (logos), so god doesn't want us to do the impossible or evil, and can't contradict himself.  God allows evil with "permissive will" - He sees it in the eternal present and takes it into account on His plan, also outside of time, but does not wish it - another free agent decides. Actually Judas was usually depicted in Hell (e.g. Dante) as non-repentant traitor/suicidal, so no "saint judas".  Felix Culpa is really related: Good come from it, as God takes the Fall on His plan - yet Adam/Eva were punished, it was their fault.